# PHP return string without "echo"?

Tags: php

I have a class containing a lot of "return" functions :

```
Class Components_superclass
{
    public function build()
    {
        $this->add_category('Grille');  
    }

    public function add_category($name)
    {
        return '<div class="category">'. $name .'</div>';
    }
    ...
}
```

I want to get the html code containing in "add_category" function. But when I echo this, I have nothing :

```
$component = new Components_superclass();
echo $component->build();
```

Must I add "return" in build function ? Is there a way to avoid this ? Because I have a lot of function to call and I don't want to write something like this :

```
public function build()
{
     return 
        $this->function_1() .
        $this->function_2() .
        $this->function_3();
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Many people (usually newbie programmers) tend to think that programming languages have these magic features build right in. Well, they don't. Programming is programming, meaning you have to do the programming part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `echo` doesn't work because nothing is returned from build – there is not string that's passed into echo which could be printed.

About your second question, you could buffer the string internally and then return it at once, like this:

```
Class Components_superclass
{
    private $buffer = array();

    // …

    public function add_category($name)
    {
        $this->buffer[] = '<div class="category">'. $name .'</div>';
    }

    public function output()
    {
        return implode('', $this->buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good idea! I had not thought of that way that makes the most sense. I am a noob ! Thanks.

Comment: It would be better to only store `$name` in the buffer, without the HTML (why use up the extra memory?). Then append the HTML when outputting only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function to return a value (that can be a string, integer or other types) use `return`. If you call the function, the returned value is then available on that place.

If `function_1()` return the string 'I am function one' and you echo the function call (`echo $this->function_1();`), the string 'I am function one' will be echoed.

This is also the correct way of working with functions. If you want to echo thing from inside the function, just echo in the function.

Check out [PHP.net's function documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php)!

Comment: Yes but I want to manipulate the strings "ouputed". If I echo them in my class, then I can't put them in a variable.

Comment: Correct, that is way you should never echo something in a funcion. You van 'gather' all strings in the flush function and return it to your interface and echo it there?